# Internal server error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internal-server-error

I an trying to open my root page it shows error "Internal server error"

```
=> Booting Thin
```

=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:4000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4000, CTRL+C to stop
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set `secret_key_base`. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from require at /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/bin/rails:9)
Unexpected error while processing request: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in`env_config'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in`call'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in`block in pre_process'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in`pre_process'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in`receive_data'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in`run'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in`start'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in`start'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in`block in server'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`server'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/bin/rails:9:in`'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`load'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /home/smk/test/test/BMS-New/bin/spring:13:in`'
    bin/rails:3:in `load'
    bin/rails:3:in`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config/secrets.yml` file remove everything add this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: bcbfd4e5010b035e62898f964188362877783b43f94bf883cf4b1d82d9224349789fb9dd0c2f33a200acfa266024a285e324caa3b20d0a9a352014156e47ec5c

test:
  secret_key_base: af068d8662bf954a2afeb27c64bbcdeb56b730029272bd3daff7e00c3c076999b3d2297747a3cef0550d3efd5cf8072e0477b8a62f096c94ab124f0d99320d20

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Your error refers that in your `secrets.yml` file `secret_key_base` and `secret_token` is missing.

**FYI:**  You can change the `secret_key_base` as you like. If you don't have this file then create one. For different environment the `secret_key_base` will be different. You should add the environment there also. Here, I give key base for `development/production/test` environment

Comment: i dont have the file config/secrets.yml

Comment: hi, please vote my question.. my account was locked due to no votes.. please vote my question Emu